# inserting parentheses and asterisks into string according to some conditions

Tags: java, string, boolean-expression

I have the following method which is used to insert parentheses and asterisks into a boolean expression when dealing with multiplication. For instance, an input of `A+B+AB` will give `A+B+(A*B)`.

However, I also need to take into account the primes (apostrophes). The following are some examples of input/output:

`A'B'+CD` should give `(A'*B')+(C*D)`

`A'B'C'D'` should give `(A'*B'*C'*D')`

`(A+B)'+(C'D')` should give `(A+B)'+(C'*D')`

I have tried the following code but seems to have errors. Any thoughts?

```
public static String modify(String expression)
    {
        String temp = expression;
        StringBuilder validated = new StringBuilder();
        boolean inBrackets=false;

        for(int idx=0; idx<temp.length()-1; idx++)
        {
            //no prime
            if((Character.isLetter(temp.charAt(idx))) && (Character.isLetter(temp.charAt(idx+1))))
            {
                if(!inBrackets)
                {
                    inBrackets = true;
                    validated.append("(");
                }
                validated.append(temp.substring(idx,idx+1));
                validated.append("*");
            }

            //first prime
            else if((Character.isLetter(temp.charAt(idx))) && (temp.charAt(idx+1)=='\'') && (Character.isLetter(temp.charAt(idx+2))))
            {
                if(!inBrackets)
                {
                    inBrackets = true;
                    validated.append("(");
                }
                validated.append(temp.substring(idx,idx+2));
                validated.append("*");
                idx++;
            }

            //second prime
            else if((Character.isLetter(temp.charAt(idx))) && (temp.charAt(idx+2)=='\'') && (Character.isLetter(temp.charAt(idx+1))))
            {
                if(!inBrackets)
                {
                    inBrackets = true;
                    validated.append("(");
                }
                validated.append(temp.substring(idx,idx+1));
                validated.append("*");
                idx++;
            }

            else
            {
                validated.append(temp.substring(idx,idx+1));
                if(inBrackets)
                {
                    validated.append(")");
                    inBrackets=false;
                }
            }
        }
        validated.append(temp.substring(temp.length()-1));
        if(inBrackets)
        {
            validated.append(")");
            inBrackets=false;
        }
        return validated.toString();
    }
```

Your help will greatly be appreciated. Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: can you post that error which you got...?

Comment: well at first glance you don't seem to handle the (A+B)'+(C'D') case where first character is a parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you should start with positions of `+` character in your string. If they differ by 1, you dont do anything. If they differ by two then there are two possiblities: `AB` or `A'`. So you check for it. If they differ by more than 2, then just check for `'` symbol and put required symbol.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in 2 passes using regular expressions:

```
StringBuilder input = new StringBuilder("A'B'+(CDE)+A'B");

Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile("[A-Z]'?(?=[A-Z]'?)");
Matcher matcher1 = pattern1.matcher(input);
while (matcher1.find()) {
    input.insert(matcher1.end(), '*');
    matcher1.region(matcher1.end() + 1, input.length());
}
Pattern pattern2 = Pattern.compile("([A-Z]'?[*])+[A-Z]'?");
Matcher matcher2 = pattern2.matcher(input);
while (matcher2.find()) {

    int start = matcher2.start();
    int end = matcher2.end();
    if (start==0||input.charAt(start-1) != '(') {
        input.insert(start, '(');
        end++;
    }
    if (input.length() == end || input.charAt(end) != ')') {
        input.insert(end, ')');
        end++;
    }
    matcher2.region(end, input.length());
}
```

It works as follows: the regex [A-Z]'? will match a letter from A-Z (all the capital letters) and it can be followed by an optional apostrophe, so it conveniently takes care of whether there is an apostrophe or not for us. The regex [A-Z]'?(?=[A-Z]'?) then means "look for a capital letter followed by an option apostrophe and then look for (but don't match against) a capital letter followed by an option apostrophe. This wil be all the places after which you want to put an asterisk. We then create a Matcher and find all the characters that match it. then we insert the asterisk. Since we modified the string, we need to update the Matcher for it to function properly.

In the second pass, we use the regex ([A-Z]'?[*])+[A-Z]'? which will look for "a capital letter followed by an option apostrophe and then an asterisk at least one time and then a capital letter followed by an option apostrophe". this is where all the groups that parentheses need to go in lie. So we create a Matcher and find the matches. we then check to see if there is already a parentese there (making sure not to go out of bounds ). If not we add a one. We again need to update the Matcher since we inserted characters. once this is over we have or final string.

for more on regex:

- [Pattern documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)
- [Regex tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)